# How do I make a model fields into a dropdown choice in another model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7

I want to create a form which has the fields of another model.The dropdown items will be the fileds not the data in that fields Is it possible? and how?

Answer (score 0):

In forms.py you can do the next thing:

```
class form(forms.Form):
  lista=[]
  for obj in model.objects.all():
     if obj not in lista:
        lista.append((obj, obj))
  field_name = forms.ChoiceField(label="", choices=lista)
```

Hope that could help you in my first post

Comment: you'll want to change your variable names ```list```, and ```object``` as these names are datatypes in python.

Comment: @EMiller, sure I just wanted to use generics names but it can be confusing, thanks for the comment.